# How do I set a different volume level for different notifications?

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey

Mac OS 12.0.1 / Monterey:

I'd like to be able to have different Notifications, both from individual applications, and (in the case of iMessage) from specific Contacts within that application, play ***at different volume levels***.

E.g. for when my normal contacts TXT / iMessage me, their notification sound plays at volume level "X" (say, 5.)

But for my designated "high priority" contacts, I'd like the volume level to be much louder, say, 10.

I could simulate this in a round-a-bout way by making a spread of different ringtones or notification sounds that have different volume levels in their source content but this is a clumsy work around.

Is there any way to do this natively (or using an API) within Mac OS 12 / Monterey?

(note, it appears a similar question [was asked more than 9 years ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47398/changing-notification-sound-for-different-notifications), but by now I'm sure the Notifications architecture is very different & presumably more advanced)

Comment: Generally speaking the _output volume setting_ is a _global setting_, however there are exceptions. One in particular is **Music**, in that its _output volume_ can be adjusted independent of the _system output  volume_, although it can not play any louder than what the _system output volume_ is set at. As far a changing the _output volume_ between the various things you've mentioned, there are no preferences settings between them to change the _output volume_ for each of them.

Comment: It'd be a great feature for Apple to add because there are really many notifications that are not that important -- but a few notifications are VERY important and those I want to hear blasting loud and clear. Should be a straightforward, no-brainer addition to the Notifications framework and APIs, I'd think.